# Swift: WKWebView not playing video from a secure URL with Headers

Tags: ios, swift, video-streaming, wkwebview

I have a secure private URL with which I have to pass two headers to get the response. 
When I am trying to load data to a WKWebView using the URL, if it an Image, it is displaying the Image on the WKWebView without any issue, but if it a Video it a just displaying a blank screen with play button and When I tap on the play button nothing happens. I waited close to 20 minutes thinking that the video is loading, even then no response.

It is identifying the correct mimetype and content type

Can someone kindly take a look at my code and tell me where I am going wrong. If there has to be any changes made to the URL or the backend, what should be made so that the URL will stream the videos or play them on webview.

This is my code:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

var request:NSMutableURLRequest!
var wkwebview: WKWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tryload()

    wkwebview = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 20, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height - 20), configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration())

    self.view.addSubview(wkwebview)
}

func tryload() {

    let headers = [
        "auth-token": "+XXXXX:XXXX:XXX",
        "Accept-Encoding": "",
        ]

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "http://example.com/api/assets/download/a235c923-ca7g-42be-81dd-89b14d0?Id=1&type=ASSET&otherId=9")! as URL,
                                      cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,
                                      timeoutInterval: 10.0)

    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers

    let session = URLSession.shared
    let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if (error != nil) {
            print("the error is \(error)")
        } else {
            let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
            print("The HTTP response is \(httpResponse)")
            print("the response is \(response?.mimeType)")
            print("the data is \(data)")

            self.wkwebview.load(request as URLRequest)
        }
    })

    dataTask.resume()

}
}
```

Comment: Why do u even need data task for ???

Comment: @SandeepBhandari Just to check the response of the request. Even when the try to load the request to wkwebview before the datatask, the result is same! Any chance you can help me solve this

Comment: implement all the delegates of WKWebView like navigation delegates and check if u are receiving any authentication challenge

Comment: implement uiDelegate as well if the response from the url has _blank or javascript code to open new window/tab window.open() uiDelegate createWebViewWithConfiguration gets called. Let us know whats the issue we will help u out

Comment: @SandeepBhandari Thanks! I tried implementing all the delegates but then I could not understand where it is going wrong. With the same implementation I tried putting a dropbox link with video and it is playing the video!

Comment: Looks like ur link has some issue. Did u check didFailWithError ? U sure there was no error ?

Comment: yeah! I tried that as well but no results. What does an ideal secure URL be like in order for iOS to play the video. Because the same link if it has an image, wkwebview is displaying the image without any issue. The issue is only with videos.

Comment: not really sure I understand ur question. You should check how video streaming is done ? Is that video playing when u open link in safari (iPhone browser)

Comment: No it is not because, I need to pass the authtoken header with the URL. But if I put in postman! I can see the video.